# Sortable work queue software or design pattern

Tags: message-queue, priority-queue, task-queue

I need to build something spec'd out as "a work queue".  The queue would hold a few different types of actionable items which a pool of users would pull from using various priority orders.  It should be accessible via programatic API.

I've looked at Amazon's SQS, ActiveMQ, and a couple others but nothing really supports ad-hoc queue sorting, or the ability to view everything on the queue without removing items.

I'm thinking that a queue might be incorrect for what I need, but at the same time I feel like what I do need should already exist, and I don't want to re-invent the wheel.

Does anybody know of any particular software, or class of software, or even just a general design pattern that would be applicable to what I need to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more meetings, I realized I was being asked to rebuild a ticketing system like Bugzilla or JIRA or Mantis.  I'm not sure why my brain wasn't able to make the leap from "work queue" to "ticketing system".